# Audacity freezes when attempting to record from my blue snowball microphone, while it's plugged into a hub

Tags: usb, microphone, audio-recording, audacity, hub

Audacity, by and large, works fine for me. I use Linux Mint 19 at the moment. When I have my Blue Snowmall microphone plugged in directly, it has zero issues reading from it.

However, when I plug that microphone into a USB hub, specifically Ativa USB 2.0 4-port, set it to read from that mic (it does recognize it as possible input, my machine knows it's there), and press record, it locks up until I stop recording or use something like Pulse Audio Volume Control to switch devices. No audio read, no scrub bar movement, nothing.

This is *only* while it's trying to read from that microphone, the moment I switch to something else, even hot, it goes about its business like nothing happened.

I am officially out of ideas, and am resorting to plugging it in directly. Is there a reason why a USB hub (which works fine for things like thumb drives or manual input) would be unable to be used for recording sound? Is there a history of problems similar to this? I don't think it's a power issue, as the hub is externally powered, but is that a possibility?

Any input on this is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the USB hub powered?  I'd suggest trying a powered one.  I'd also suggest trying a USB extension cable rather than a hub.  Be aware of the maximum length of about 15 feet.

Comment: It is powered. I'm currently using an extension cable, but I hardly need one and it would be nice to have it back.